# Border Spacing in Tailwind React

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

So, I want to execute the following css on a div:

```
border-spacing:0
```

How, to achieve this in tailwind. I read about adding utilities but didn't understand how to do so in Reactjs.

Note:
I want to have border-separate and border-spacing-0 so that border remains intact with the header.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method can helps you

```
// tailwind.config.js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addUtilities }) {
      const newUtilities = {
        '.filter-none': {
          filter: 'none',
        },
        '.filter-grayscale': {
          filter: 'grayscale(100%)',
        },
      }

      addUtilities(newUtilities, ['responsive', 'hover'])
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can I add something to tailwind.config.js ?

Comment: I don't get your mean, but you can add everything in tailwind.config.js

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can do it using your `input.css` adding:

```
table { 
  border-spacing: 0; {/* or anything else */}
}
```

as a general option and run this line of code to build your output as `tailwind.css` using in your app:

```
npx tailwindcss --input path/to/your/input.css  --output path/to/your/tailwind.css --minify
```

tailwind doesn't limit you to its styling classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is not only applying css to tailwind but also the installation of tailwind in reactjs, to do that read [this installation guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app)

And to add the border spacing class to a div do

`<div className="border-spacing-0"> </div>`